# Can I add a whole specific datataframe column as a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, legend

I would like to insert a specific dataframe column (the column "labels" in the dataframe below) as part of a ggplot2 plot legend, considering that the column is not being used in the plot. I've tryed to use argument `tag` inside `labs` but I only get the first line of the column.

Here is the plot code:

```
id=c(1,2,3,4)
x=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)
y1=c(10,20,30,40)
y2=c(300,400,500,640)
labels=c('1-A','2-B','3-C','4-D')
df<-data.table(id=id,x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2,labels=labels)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x))
(p+geom_point(aes(y=y1, colour='y1'))
        +geom_text(aes(y=y1,label=id, colour='y1'),show.legend = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
        +geom_point(aes(y=y2/16, colour = 'y2'))
        +geom_text(aes(y=y2/16,label=id, colour = 'y2'),show.legend  = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
        +scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*16, name = 'y2'))
        +labs(tag = df$labels) 
        +theme(plot.tag.position = c(0.98, 0.6),legend.title = element_blank()
               ,legend.justification ='top', plot.margin = unit(c(1,4,1,1),"lines"))
)
df
   id   x y1  y2 labels
1:  1 0.1 10 300    1-A
2:  2 0.2 20 400    2-B
3:  3 0.3 30 500    3-C
4:  4 0.4 40 640    4-D
```

And what i get is [this plot, with only the first line of the column "labels" of the dataframe showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDnHc.png)

Is there a way to insert the whole column "labels" below the legend?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I've figured it out using @tacoman sugestion (`fill=labels`) together with `legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)` inside `theme` and `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=NA)))`.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x))
(p+geom_point(aes(y=y1, colour='y1', fill=labels))
        +geom_text(aes(y=y1,label=id, colour='y1'),show.legend = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
        +geom_point(aes(y=y2/16, colour = 'y2'))
        +geom_text(aes(y=y2/16,label=id, colour = 'y2'),show.legend  = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
        +scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*16, name = 'y2'))
        +theme(legend.title = element_blank()
               ,legend.justification ='top', plot.margin = unit(c(1,4,1,1),"lines")
               ,legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
        +guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=NA)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like  this? Simply add `fill = labels`.

```
id=c(1,2,3,4)
x=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)
y1=c(10,20,30,40)
y2=c(300,400,500,640)
labels=c('1-A','2-B','3-C','4-D')
df<-data.table(id=id,x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2,labels=labels)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x))
(p+geom_point(aes(y=y1, colour='y1', fill = labels))
  +geom_text(aes(y=y1,label=id, colour='y1'),show.legend = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
  +geom_point(aes(y=y2/16, colour = 'y2'))
  +geom_text(aes(y=y2/16,label=id, colour = 'y2'),show.legend  = F,hjust=0, vjust=0,nudge_x=0)
  +scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*16, name = 'y2'))
  +theme(plot.tag.position = c(0.98, 0.6),legend.title = element_blank()
         ,legend.justification ='top', plot.margin = unit(c(1,4,1,1),"lines"))
)
```

Comment: Yes, this would be it! But I need it without the dots in the legend generated by fill=labels. Im trying to figure it out without success. Is there a way to hide the dots in the legend? Thank you!